# AngularJS: Sharing Data between 3 Controllers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-factory

I am using factory method in AngularJS to show the combination of First Name and Last Name (first two controllers) as Full Name(in third Controller), but i am not getting the desired output. here is my code:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
   <div ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
   <input type="text" ng-model="Data.FirstName">
   <br>FirstName is : <strong>{{Data.FirstName}}</strong>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
            <input type="text" ng-model="Data.LastName">
    <br>LastName is : <strong>{{Data.LastName}}</strong>
  </div>
       <div ng-controller="ThirdCtrl">
   FullName is : {{Data.FirstName + " " + Data.LastName}}
  </div>

 </div>
 </div>

    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


        myApp.factory('Data', function () {
            return { FirstName: '',LastName:'' };
        });

        myApp.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope, Data) {
            $scope.Data = Data;
        });

        myApp.controller('SecondCtrl', function ($scope, Data) {
            $scope.Data = Data;
        });
        myApp.controller('ThirdCrl', function ($scope, Data) {
            $scope.Data = Data;
        }); 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you please Help?

Comment: ThirdCtrl is mispelled

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
   <div ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
   <input type="text" ng-model="Data.FirstName">
   <br>FirstName is : <strong>{{Data.FirstName}}</strong>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
            <input type="text" ng-model="Data.LastName">
    <br>LastName is : <strong>{{Data.LastName}}</strong>
  </div>
       <div ng-controller="ThirdCtrl">
   FullName is : {{Data.FirstName + " " + Data.LastName}}
  </div>

 </div>
 </div>

    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


        myApp.factory('Data', function () {
            return { FirstName: '',LastName:'' };
        });

        myApp.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope, Data) {
            $scope.Data = Data;
        });

        myApp.controller('SecondCtrl', function ($scope, Data) {
            $scope.Data = Data;
        });
        myApp.controller('ThirdCtrl', function ($scope, Data) {
            $scope.Data = Data;
        }); 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have spelled wrongly the third controller name.

Comment: when you are getting errors such as  'Error: [ng:areq] ', its because the function you declared is undefined. In the above case, you declared the controller named as 'ThirdCtrl', but you haven't defined the function (because of spell mistake).